# Calculate new probability based on past probability per value

Tags: probability

I want to calculate a percentage probability based on a list of past occurrences.
The data looks similar to this simplified table, for instance when the first value has been 8 in the past there has been a 72% chance of the event occurring.

```
1   76%
2   64%
4   80%
6   85%
7   83%
8   72%
11  70%
```

The full table ranges from 0 to 1030 and has 377 rows but changes daily.  I want pass the function a value such as 3 and be returned a percentage probability of the event occurring.  I don't need exact code, but would appreciate being pointed in the right direction.
Thanks

Comment: Thank you Phil, that looks much better.

Comment: How sure are you that the two are related? Since the value at 2 is only 6% below the value at 11, but 12% and 16% away from the values at 1 and 4, what can you infer about 3? Should it be halfway between the values at 2 and 4?

Comment: The values are related but somewhat vaguely and some of the values in column 1 occur more often than others or not at all.  So no it is not as simple as just being halfway between the lower and higher values. In the actual table the probability tends to drop off as the number in column 1 increases.  Is there a way I can send you the actual data?

Comment: Perhaps upload it to Google Docs, and supply a sharing link, assuming it is in a spreadsheet. Otherwise, dropbox?

Comment: Thanks.  Here is the link: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B2t7XdkVSIIxZ05XVnpnMS1MN1U

Comment: Up to now I've blocked the value into groups, 1-50,51-100,101,150, etc and used the average probability of the group the new value falls into.  But I'm hoping that there is a more elegant solution to this as I'm wanting to expand the process to include different data that can't easily be grouped.

Comment: What is it you want to do inference about? Outcomes that exist in the data already, or new values? If new values, are they in the same range as the data currently, or outside of it? I ask because the most accurate prediction will likely depend on the answer to this.

Comment: I want to compare a new value that will be within the current high - low range of values (Column 1), say 1-1000, but may not be one of the exact numbers in the data.  From this I want to calculate an outcome probability based on the percentages in Column 3.  Column 2 shows the total times the value in Column 1 occurred, Column 3 shows the percentage of times the value in Column 1 resulted in a positive outcome.  The data table grows as new occurrences are added.

Comment: From looking at the data, the first question I would wonder about is "how likely is it that there is no relationship between the 2 numbers?", i.e. is is plausible that the 2 variables are just independent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your answers in the comments of the question, I would suggest an interpolation---linear interpolation is the simplest answer. It doesn't look like a probabilistic model would be appropriate based on the series in the spreadsheet (there doesn't appear to be a clear relationship between the column 1 and column 3).

To give an example of how this would work: imagine you want the probability for some point p, which is unobserved in the data. The biggest value you observe which is *less* than p is p_low (with corresponding probability f(p_low)), and the smallest value greater than p is p_high (with probability f(p_high)). Your estimate for p is:

```
interval = p_high - p_low
f_p_hat = ((p-p_low)/interval*f_p_low) + ((p_high-p)/interval*f_p_high)
```

This is going to make your estimate for p a weighted average of the values at p_low and p_high, with weights given by the distances between p and p_low, and p and p_high. E.g. if p is equidistant between p_low and p_high, f_p_hat (your estimate for f(p)) is just the mean of p_low and p_high.

Now, linear interpolation may not work if you have reason to suspect that the estimates at the endpoints are inaccurate (possibly due to small sample sizes). If so, it would be possible to do a (possibly weighted) least squares fit to a neighbourhood of points around p, and use that as a prediction. If this is the case I can go into a bit more detail.

Comment: Thanks Ben.  I'll give this a try and see how it performs for a few weeks.  Your second option to include more of the surrounding data points may be more valid and I will experiment with that also. I appreciate your help.